# Not able to run test on existing opened browser of Chrome uisng coded ui but On it is possible

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I have to run Coded ui code test on existing opened instance of chrome browser. For that I have intsalled cross browser plugin for chrome and used below code to run ==>

```
BrowserWindow browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
if (BrowserWindow.Locate("Google").Exists)
{
    BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
    browserWindow = BrowserWindow.Locate("Google");
    browserWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    //mParentWindow = BrowserWindow.Locate("odrive");
    //mParentWindow.Maximized = !mParentWindow.Maximized;
}

UITestControl Control = new UITestControl(browserWindow);
Control.TechnologyName = "Web";
Control.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Document");
Control.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "lst-ib");
// Control.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", "FirstName LastName");
Control.DrawHighlight();
```

But I am getting below exception while locating BrowserWindow.

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not
>   handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely cannot accomplish this with the Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing. The WebDriver implementations require that the driver is what launched the browser instance being controlled. This is clearly stated in Microsoft's documentation for using the Selenium components. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx), in the section marked "What else should I know?"

Comment: How it is possible on IE Browser...and why not chrome ,.... i mean anything is missed out in chrome or not supported

Comment: Coded UI Tests don't use the Selenium library to automate IE. Thus, the framework isn't bound by the same restrictions for automating IE.